# Create a temporary file with unique name using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, temp

I would like to create a temporary file with an specific name (and if its possible with an specific extension).

Example:

```
-mytempfile.txt
-mytempfile2.xml
```

I've been reading about tempfile library, but as far as I know I can only set the following parameters

```
(mode='w+b', buffering=None, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None)
```

Comment: If you do fopen on a file which doesnt exist, it will create it. You can delete it at the end of your program

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @RemyJ OP showed effort by listing `tempfile` package and concerning about lost parameter.

Comment: Check [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile). It doesn't provide name specification, but you can use generated name to open the file a second time.

Comment: @vishes_shell OK, it's just that I was expecting a some code.

Comment: My bad guys. I forgot to say I'm new at coding.If you want the short story. I need to create an .xml file which will be inside a .zip file encoded on base64 (both files need an specific name), then sent the .zip to a SOAP ws. I'd do this easily by using 'import os' then create and delete files however i would like to. BUT, here's the catch. I'm running my python scripts inside a Saas environment. I cannot use 'os' because of a permission issue.I can only create temporary files.So creating a temporary .xml is my first step to the solution I thought of.I tried to explain it as short as possible.

Answer (score 8):

The most secure method to do what you are asking for is, as Dan points out there is no need to specify any name to the file, I am only using suffix and prefix as OP asked for it in the question.

```
import os
import tempfile as tfile
fd, path = tfile.mkstemp(suffix=".txt",prefix="abc") #can use anything 
try:
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmpo:
        # do stuff with temp file
        tmpo.write('something here')
finally:
    os.remove(path)
```

to understand more about the security aspects attached to this you can refer to this [link](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_using-temporary-files-securely.html)

well if you can't use os and are required to perform these actions then consider using the following code.

```
import tempfile as tfile
temp_file=tfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w",suffix=".xml",prefix="myname")
a=temp_file.name

temp_file.write("12")
temp_file.close()
```

a will give you the complete path to the file eg as:

> '/tmp/mynamesomething.xml'

in case you don't want to delete the file in the end then use:

```
temp_file=tfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) #along with other parameters of course.
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to care about the name of the file.  In fact, it's critical that you _not_ specify a full temporary file name to make sure the name is and always will be unique.  Using `tempfile` is a strong suggestion, because it automatically guarantees tempfile uniqueness, and it also automatically cleans up after itself.

Comment: @Dan Farrell thanks for the suggestion, made edits to include this important point.

Comment: Thanks@Inder I'll take a look at the link you provided me. Also if you guys feel like getting the whole picture. I just explain why I want to create temporary files with specific names, on a comment to the original post.

Comment: @jajdp updated my answer kindly check if it satisfy your requirements

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, actually I'm currently finding new ways to achieve what I want. Your code is helping me understand this better. I'm giving you a thumb up for the moment. This might take a few days... I'll update this post when I have a solid answer and understanding of what would be the best way to do this. Thanks~